# Attempt to invoke virtual method...on a null object reference error?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

My program opens with a login page, then moves to a page with two buttons (go to counter and go to scan barcode).

Very basic at this point, but I'm stuck because I press the scan barcode button and it moves to the new page fine, but if I press the 'go to counter' button (which goes to a chronometer class), the program crashes - even though there is a class made for it.

It gives me this error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference.

Here is my code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class page1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button scanner,go2count;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);

    scanner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanner);
    go2count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go2count);

    scanner.setOnClickListener(this);
    go2count.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.scanner:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ScanPage.class));
            break;

        case R.id.go2count:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ChronoPage.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

So if I press the 'scanner' button, it works fine. But if I press the 'go2count' button, the program gives me the error mentioned.

This is the chronometer code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ChronoPage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button start;
private Button stop;
private Button resume;
private Button reset;
private long time = 0;

private Chronometer myChrono;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    uI();
}

public void uI(){
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);

    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);

    resume = (Button) findViewById((R.id.bResume));
    resume.setOnClickListener(this);

    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReset);
    reset.setOnClickListener(this);

    myChrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    if (v == start){
        myChrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        myChrono.start();
    }
    else if (v == stop){
        time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        myChrono.stop();
       // printing();
    }
    else if (v == resume){
        myChrono.setBase(myChrono.getBase() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - time);
        myChrono.start();
    }
    else if (v == reset){
        myChrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    }
}
```

}

Another post said to try unchecking the "Use Host GPU" in the AVD manager, but that didn't solve the problem either.
Other posts have the same error, but are more specific to their code. All help is appreciated!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/logo1"
     android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="150dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:src="@drawable/swordlogocopy"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scanner"
    android:text="Scan Barcode"
    android:textColor="#DDC004"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/go2count"
    android:text="Go to counter"
    android:textColor="#DDC004"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And the XML layout of the Chrono Page:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo1"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/swordlogocopy"/>

<Chronometer
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/chronometer1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/bStart"
    android:textColor="#DDC004"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stop"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#DDC004"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/bStop" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/resume"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#DDC004"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/bResume" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/reset"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#DDC004"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/bReset" />
```

Comment: It is difficult to tell which of your buttons is null without the line from the logcat or your XML layouts. But as the answer below points out. `findViewById` returns `null` if it is unable to find the id

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, then most likely the findViewById(id) is not finding your Button variable in your xml to set the corresponding Button and therefore returning null. Which results in a NullpointerException when trying to set a OnClickListener on this view

Check if all Button Ids are valid